# Remove default field theming in a module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I was just wondering how to remove the default theming divs of a field in Drupal 7, from within a module (so not with a theme function!!).

In my case: I implemented my own field in a module, now I'm using hook_field_formatter_view to display it. I read [here](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7) that you can implement your own MYMODULE_theme() function in your module to declare a new field formatter.. but some default divs are still there:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-myfield field-label-above">
  <div class="field-items">   <-- this one
    <div class="field-item even">   <-- and also this one
      <div id="my-own-field-div">
```

Is there a way to hide/edit them? I know of the template functions but its better to have the code inside the module..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [Fences](http://drupal.org/project/fences).